# Image sequence of 1500 frames to loop 30 times in a 30 min video FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, infinite-loop

Really struggling to get this to work, I just need to loop an image sequence. It is 25fps and exactly one second in duration (1500) I need this to basically loop for 30 mins, so it will loop 30 times. Using FFMPEG, here is the working 1500 frames being converted to MP4, like i said it has to be 30 mins in length:

```
ffmpeg -i "input_%04d.jpg" -c:v libx264 -b:v 1M -s 1080x810 -crf 28 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-loop 1` as an input option for an infinite loop, and then use `-t 00:30:00` as an output option to cut off the video at thirty minutes. I would also suggest that you have a look at the [H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264), and the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/) in general.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "input_%04d.jpg" -c:v libx264 -s 1080x810 -preset veryfast -crf 28 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 00:30:00 out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, worked fine.. I must have ordered the loop function wrong before! I had read up but couldn't actually get it to work.

Comment: note for ffmpeg 0.7.13 on osx, `-loop 1` should be `-loop_input`.

Comment: What if the images do not have similar names, can it be done with concat and a file list?